# Slow rotate onscroll effect js

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Hey there i found a way to rotate my svg with this

```
var leftgear = document.getElementById("spin"),
rightgear = document.getElementById("spin2");

window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
    leftgear.style.transform = "rotate("+window.pageYOffset+"deg)";
    rightgear.style.transform = "rotate(-"+window.pageYOffset+"deg)";
});
```

The problem i'm facing is that it spins much too fast. It needs to be slowed down by at least 70%.
Also i'm unable to use jquery as i'm using vue.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to change it to 70%, just do this:

```
 var leftgear = document.getElementById("spin"),
    rightgear = document.getElementById("spin2");
    var multiplier = 0.7;
    window.addEventListener("scroll", function() {
        leftgear.style.transform = "rotate("+window.pageYOffset*multiplier+"deg)";
        rightgear.style.transform = "rotate(-"+window.pageYOffset*multiplier+"deg)";
    });
```

You can change the multiplier to whatevery you want and it will go at a different speed.

Comment: Oh I forgot a car in front of the multiplier. Sorry